# How do I swap (non-background) images based on detected browser language?

Tags: html, css, image, web, lang

I'd like to:

1. Display one url image in a paragraph tag (French flag) that, 
   a. hyperlinks to one url, AND
   b. is displayed based on the detected browser language fr_ca

AND

2. Display a different url image in a paragraph tag (American flag) that,
   a. hyperlinks to a different url from above, AND
   b. is displayed based on the detected browser language en, AND
   c. hides the fr_ca paragraph tag above

I have access only to the CSS and HTML inline or via style block (not CSS file) or other server-side scripts.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking but not sure how to execute:

```
    <p .lang_fr_ca><a href="http://www.company.com/shop/change-store.ep?store=STORE_CA&amp;locale=fr_CA" target="_parent"><img alt="" class="flag" data-pin-nopin="true" src="http://static.company.com/shop/template-resources/~1336/images/flags/64/ca.png" /></a>

    <p .lang_en><a href="http://www.company.com/shop/change-store.ep?store=STORE_US&amp;locale=en_US" target="_parent"><img alt="" class="flag" data-pin-nopin="true" src="http://static.company.com/shop/template-resources/~1336/images/flags/64/us.png" /></a></p>
```

Comment: Hm. A quick and dirty test shows that the `:lang` pseudo-class works only on html pages that have a `lang` attribute set; it's not based on OS language of browser preferences or anything. So you'd have to change your HTML anyway to make that work. In other words, this requires JavaScript or server-side manipulation.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister, let me clarify, the JS is already on a client website (yet cannot be edited), this html/css is being added into a module that is injected server-side and so needs to detect the browser lang setting but, as I cannot add additional JS, I need to implement via CSS/HTML

Comment: Then the question is, what can you do on the server side? If you can detect the user's language, the just send the appropriate content based on it.

Comment: Thanks... that's the question, how would I set that up without editing the JS (we can detect the users language)